# On delete, I get and out of bound error

Tags: apex, trigger

I get an error "List index out of bounds: 0: Trigger.trgr_Update_BOG_Members_List: line 18, column 1". " when one deletes a record. It works fine when one creates or updates a record. What to do?

```
trigger trgr_Update_BOG_Members_List on BOG_Membership__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    ID currID;

    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
    {    
        LIST<BOG_Membership__c> accountMap = [SELECT ID, Contact__r.AccountId FROM BOG_Membership__c WHERE ID IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
        for(BOG_Membership__c a: Trigger.new){
            currID = accountMap[0].Contact__r.AccountId;

        }     
    }else if (Trigger.isDelete)   
    {
        LIST<BOG_Membership__c> accountMap = [SELECT ID, Contact__r.AccountId FROM BOG_Membership__c WHERE ID IN :Trigger.oldMap.keySet()];                    
        for (BOG_Membership__c a: Trigger.old) 
        {
            currID = accountMap[0].Contact__r.AccountId;
        }
    }
    List<AggregateResult> aggregates = [
    SELECT Contact__r.AccountId , Contact__r.FirstName , Contact__r.LastName 
        FROM BOG_Membership__c 
        WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = :currID
        GROUP BY Contact__r.AccountId, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName

];

    Map<Id, Account> parentRecords = new Map<Id, Account>();
    String listNames = '';    
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : aggregates)
    {

        Id parentId = (Id)aggregate.get('accountId');
        String firstName = (String)aggregate.get('FirstName');
        String lastName = (String)aggregate.get('LastName');


        listNames += firstName + ' ' + lastName + '<br />';
        parentRecords.put(parentId, new Account(
        Id = parentId, BOG_Members_List__c = listNames
        ));


    }
    update parentRecords.values();
}
```

Comment: I am also working on related problem like this.Please provide suggestion if you got any solution @Apex N-u-b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as you are querying the records on after delete event, you wont get
>   the records that is the reason you are getting list index out of bound
>   error.

**Use before delete event instead of after delete event**

```
currID = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id =: Trigger.newMap.values()[0].Contact__c LIMIT 1].AccountId;
```

Comment: I need it after delete because my code gets the current members of a related list and if it's before delete, the person (record) still shows in the list. Does this make sense?

Comment: what is you requirement could you please share little bit more?

Comment: We have a scenario of accounts who have contacts where some have one or more records in a custom object named members__c but not all contacts have a member__c record. member__c object has a lookup relationship with the contact object. So if one creates or updates a record whoever has at least one record is populated in the BOG_Members_List__c  field. If a record is deleted, they should not show up any longer. If the trigger runs before delete, they are still showing, after delete they don't but I need a way to get the record id from the deleted record.

Comment: it should work if you use the **before delete**  because you only need the Contact__r.AccountId. Try once using before delete event.

Comment: I did but the person remains in the list. Remember the record is not removed until after delete. When it's before delete the record still exists in the database.

Comment: based on your requirement i have updated my answer, please have a look and let me know if this works

Comment: I get this error "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Map<Id,BOG_Membership__c>"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42485/discussion-between-sfdc-learner-and-apex-n-u-b).